# How do you reach the chest in the desert fortress?

Tags: candy-box-2

[image: How to reach it?]

I tried Octopus Spam with Crown, but it's not working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the tribal spear of summoning and teleport to the entrance when you hit the wall, you can make stairs with the tribesmen.

Comment: yup! here's what it looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezz75l35squb94p/Screenshot%202013-11-02%2018.37.41.png

Answer (score 2):

Summoning tribal spear + boots of introspection + pogostick

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

[image]

Tips: 
Remove every item and equip the Enchanted Knight Armor so that you will have barely no fist damage.
Go almost until the end (right) and create one wall. Then keep teleporting back and use fireballs to destroy it until the size you want.
Do this for the next and next walls.

Profit. It contains the Rocket Boots which basically allow you to fly.